# Proof that $\ln(x)$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was reading about the derivative of $\ln(x)$ using chain rule.But it requires you to know $\ln(x)$ is differentiable.Then i saw the derivative of $\ln(x)$ using limit definition of derivative but it used the limit definition of $e$ which again i think the derivative of $\ln(x)$ must be known to show that:
$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$
How should i show that $\ln(x)$ is differentiable?

Comment: Well, what is **your** definition of $\;\ln x\;$ ?

Comment: $\ln x$ is the inverse function of $e^x$, so you can use the theorem about the derivative of the inverse function.

Comment: How are you defining $\ln(x)$? If it is defined as the inverse of $e^x$, then you know it is differentiable since the inverse of a smooth, injective function is itself smooth. You certainly don’t need to know anything about $\ln(x)$ to “compute” that limit. In fact, you normally just prove that limit exists and define $e$ to be the limit. That is, that limit is not a “property” that $e$ satisfies, but the very definition of $e$ (in most contexts).

Comment: ... and other authors define $\ln$ as $\int\frac1x\mathrm dx$, which makes the question of differentiability trivial (but then you need to show the inverse relation with $\exp$)

Answer (score 0):

The limit

$$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

can be proved independently by monotonic theorem for sequences and then extended to reals

$$e=\lim_{x\to \pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+x\right)^\frac1x$$

From this result we have that for $x>0$

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\ln (x+h)-\ln x}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1x\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac hx\right)}{\frac h x} =\frac1x$$

indeed

$$\ln \left[\left(1+\frac hx\right)^{\frac xh}\right]\to \ln e=1$$

Answer (score -1):

The standard exponential function $\;f:\Bbb R\to (0,\infty)\;$ is bijective and differentiable, and we thus know there exists its inverse function $\;g=f^{-1}:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb R\;$ which is also bijective and differentiable, and this last function's derivative can be obtained by the inverse function's derivative theorem:

$$\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)'=\frac1{f'\left(f^{-1}(x)\right)}$$

Since $\;f'(x)=(e^x)'=e^x\;$ , we get $\;f'\left(e^x\right)=e^x\;$ , so if $\;y=e^x\implies x=\ln y\;$ , and then

$$(\ln y)'=\frac1{e^x}=\frac1 y\implies (\ln x)'=\frac1 x$$

and we're done.

We don't need to use the definition of $\;e\;$ you gave but rather another usual definition:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\implies (e^x)'=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^x$$

since the above power series has infinite convergence radius and can thus be termwise differentiated everywhere on $\;\Bbb R\;$ ...

Comment: The Taylor Series "definition" is reliant on the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$...

Comment: @Jared Yes, of course. I mention there that the derivative of the exponential is...etc.

Comment: I guess my main point here is that using the derivative of $e^x$ is somewhat circular. One can accept that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ and show that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ or one can accept that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$ and show that $\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. But at some point one of the two must be proved without the assumption of the other.

Comment: @Jared It is possible to prove, pretty naturally let's say, that $\;(e^x)'=e^x\;$ without even mentioning logarithms. It all depends on our definitions, of course. We could say $\;e^x\;$ is the solution to the ODE $\;y'=y\;$ , with initial condition $\;y(0)=1\;$, or we can prove the power series $\;\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}\;$ has infinite convergence radius without logarithms at all, and *define* $\;e^x\;$ as the limit (uniform in any compact subset of the reals) of that series, and from that prove what its derivative is...

Comment: You can "say" $e^x$ is the solution to the ODE all you want--that doesn't _make it_ the solution...there _is_ a reason it's the solution and it's _not_ an axiom--it does need to be proved.

Comment: Also, I'm not arguing that it can't be proved, "pretty naturally", that $\frac{d}{dx}e^x = e^x$...I'm arguing that you _didn't._

Comment: @Jared I think your missing the point: the ODE $\;y'=y\;$ with initial condition $\;y(0)=1\;$ **has** a *unique* solution (say by Picard's Theorem), then we **DEFINE** the solution to be $\;e^x\;$ ...as simple as that! This is not much basically different as proving in basic calculus that the sequence $\;\left\{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right\}\;$ is monotone ascending and bounded above and thus it has a limit which **we define** to be a number denoted by $\;e\;$ .... And I don't need to prove what the limit of $\;e^x$ , just to mention it can be obtained without **any** reference to logarithm!

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to prove that lnx is differentiable you can also use the basic definition/ formula of differentiability and knowledge of basic limits.

[image: check this]
[image: check this]

Hope this might help!

Comment: Please use mathjax for formatting your answer.